# Unity: copy data folder to another location

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, export, ini

In Unity Ive exported a PC/win 64bit version of a project we are working on, which created an .exe file and a matching data folder.

Due to software restrictions at the place where I want to give a demonstration, I'm looking for a way to copy only the data folder to another drive/location. Is there a way for the .exe file to know to look at the new location?

Ive read that using an .ini file or .xml file might be a solution, however I'm unfamiliar how to create one containing what code...

Would be wonderful if anybody could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through Unity itself.

You can use an external program for it like http://www.smartpacker.nl/smartpackerpro.html